# How can I import CSS-weighted font faces such as DemiBold, UltraBold, etc. into Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, font

I'm able to import fonts from my computer locally by simply installing the font, and then typing the full name of the font, such as "ITCKabelStd" and it works well, but whenever I try to do "ITCKabelStd-Ultra" or anything with a CSS weight of boldness font face, it doesn't detect it. It just uses the regular front "ITCKabelStd" in place of it when I put the ultra variant. I've checked my computer to make sure those font faces are installed, and they are indeed installed. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- each font variant needs to be installed as a standalone font
- make sure you are referring to the font name, not the filename

[image: 1]